# Differential equation where forcing function depends on variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

The force acting on a body depends on the displacement $x(t)$ of the body from the origin.
This dependence is given by

$$ F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
F_0 - mg, &-L < &x < 0,\\
-mg,& &x > 0.
\end{cases}
$$

where $L$ is a positive number, $F_0 > 0$ is a constant resting force and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration of Earth.

Newton's second law gives $m\ddot{x} = F(x)$ and we impose the initial conditions $\dot{x}(0) = 0, x(0) = -L.$

How does one solve an equation like this? My main problem is that if we restrict to the branch $x > 0$ we get $x = -g\frac{t^2}{2} + At + B$. I don't know if I am allowed to plug in the boundary conditions here, but if I were to, I would get $x = -g\frac{t^2}{2} - L$. But this function is clearly always negative, so then how could this satisfy the branch $x>0$?

Any tips or clarifications?

Comment: This is for something like a railgun shooting vertically upwards? So that for physical reasons $F_0>mg$?

Comment: This should model jumping vertically: in contact with the ground your legs provide a constant force $F_0$. Then you crouch and your center of mass descends $L$ meters relative to the standing position. Then $x$ is the position of your center of mass relative to the standing position and $F(x)$ is the vertical force acting on you. (it's not explicit but supposing you can actually jump it's safe to assume that $F_0 > mg$)

Comment: Ah, so a more primitive railgun. Mechanic instead of magnetic forces, a less streamlined projectile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to solve two ODE's. First solve the ODE for $x\in[-L,0)$ using your initial conditions $\dot{x}(0)=0$, $x(0)=-L$. That equation is valid until $x=0$. Then you can get values of $\dot{x}$ for when $x=0$. That is your new initial condition to use when solving the second ODE.

Comment: Let me know if I got this straight: the ODE on $x\in(-L,0)$ gives $x = \left( \frac{F_0}{m} - g \right) \frac{t^2}{2}  - L$. Now at $x = 0$ we get $t = \sqrt{\frac{2L}{\frac{F_0}{m} -g}}$. Call this $t_0$. Now I want to solve $\ddot{x} = -g$ with initial conditions $x(t_0) = 0, \dot{x}(t_0) = $ whatever it gives when plugging into the first solution?

Comment: Yes, that will do the trick. However for the first ODE, you can make your life a bit easier by making the substitution 
\begin{align}
v=\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}, 
\end{align}
and via the chain rule
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}=v\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}.
\end{align}
Effectively we eliminate the dependency on time in favor of a dependency on position, as we just care about finding the speed at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

From

$$
m\ddot x = F(x) = \left(\theta(x+L)-\theta(x)\right)(F_0-m g)- m g\theta(x)
$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function, we have

$$
m\ddot x\dot x = F(x)\dot x
$$

or equivalently with $v = \dot x$

$$
m v dv = F(x)dx
$$

and then

$$
\frac 12 m v^2 = (x+L)(F_0-m g)\theta(x+L)-x F_0\theta(x)+C_0
$$

now assuming that $v(-L) =  0\Rightarrow C_0=0$ we have

$$
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+L)(F_0-m g)\theta(x+L)-x F_0\theta(x)}} = \sqrt{\frac 2m}dt
$$

now assuming $-L \le x \le 0$

$$
\int_{-L}^x\frac{du}{\sqrt{(u+L)(F_0- m g)}}= \sqrt{\frac 2m}t
$$

giving

$$
x(t) = \frac{t^2 (F_0-g m)}{2 m}-L
$$

and for $x > 0$

$$
\int_{-L}^0\frac{du}{\sqrt{(u+L)(F_0- m g)}}+\int_0^x\frac{du}{\sqrt{(u+L)(F_0- m g)-u F_0}}= \sqrt{\frac 2m}t
$$

giving

$$
\frac{2L}{\sqrt{L(F_0-m g)}}+\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{L (F_0-m g)}-\sqrt{F_0 L-m g(L+x)}\right)}{m g} = \sqrt{\frac 2m}t
$$

and now inverting we can find $x(t)$

$$
x(t) = \frac{F_0}{g m-F_0}-1+\frac{ F_0 L \sqrt{\frac{2}{m}}}{\sqrt{L (F_0-g m)}}t-\frac{g}{2}t^2
$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks. Now I think it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The motion is a sequence of two uniformly accelerated movements. The first is immediately found to be

$$x(t)=(f_0-g)\frac{t^2}2-L$$ and $$\dot x(t)=(f_0-g)t.$$

$x$ cancels after

$$t^*=\sqrt{\frac{2L}{f_0-g}}$$ seconds, with speed $$v^*=\sqrt{2L(f_0-g)}.$$

Then the motion continues as

$$x(t)=-g\frac{(t-t^*)^2}2+v^*(t-t^*).$$

---

$f_0:=\dfrac{F_0}m.$